# How do you style custom data grid toolbar items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I have this toolbar with 2 custom buttons and 3 imported material data grid toolbar components, I want them to match but preferably apply the material styles to my custom components yet I can't find a style import for them anywhere in their docs. But anyway I can get them to match would be huge. Does anyone have some advice?

```js
  const Toolbar = () => {
    return (
      <GridToolbarContainer>
        <div
          className={classes.toolbar}
          onClick={() => {
            toggleSearch();
          }}
        >
          <SearchIcon />
          <p>SEARCH</p>
        </div>
        <div
          className={classes.toolbar}
          onClick={() => {
            bookmarkCases(selectedRows);
          }}
        >
          <BookmarkBorderIcon />
          <p>SAVE CASES</p>
        </div>
        <GridColumnsToolbarButton />
        <GridDensitySelector />
        <GridToolbarExport />
      </GridToolbarContainer>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making an icon button out of a `<div>`, why not use the `startIcon` prop in an MUI `<Button />`, e.g.

From this:

```
<div
 className={classes.toolbar}
 onClick={() => {toggleSearch()}}
 >
 <SearchIcon />
 <p>SEARCH</p>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<Button
  className={classes.toolbar}
  onClick={() => {toggleSearch()}}
  startIcon={<SearchIcon />}
 >Search
</Button>
```

All the styles should match because MUI DataGrid toolbar buttons are just MUI Buttons

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of a struggle I found a solution. I was able to achieve a consistent style for all toolbar buttons by passing the styles through the DataGrid itself.

```
  export const StyledDataDrid = styled(DataGridPremium)<DataGridPremiumProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  '& .MuiDataGrid-toolbarContainer': {
    '& .MuiButton-text': {
      fontSize: '16px !important',
      color: '#074682',
    },
    '& .MuiBadge-badge': {
      backgroundColor: '#074682',
    },
  },
}));
```

Or you can style it on the DataGrid component using the sx property as explained in this issue: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/3686#issuecomment-1018469717

Answer (score 0):

Making them MUI Buttons with `size="small"` and putting the icons in the `startIcon` prop should make them look identical:

```
<Button
  size="small"
  startIcon={<SearchIcon />}
>
  Search
</Button>

<Button
  size="small"
  startIcon={<BookmarkBorderIcon />}
>
  Save Cases
</div>
```